# Pygame Graphics: Mouse Control.

Tags: python

i'm making a little game in Python 3.6.0 I've figured out movement with "wasd" but I am having difficulty figuring out how to make my character face the direction I want by making it follow the arrow on my mouse. Any suggestions for the code bellow?

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 700))

keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
y=100
z=100
FPS=70
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        y=y+2
        if y > 900:
            y=900
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        y=y-2
        if y<0:
            y=0
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        z=z+2
        if z>700:
            z=700
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        z=z-2
        if z<0:
            z=0


    COLOUR2 = (32,59,202)
    COLOUR = (0,180,0)
    COLOUR3 =(1,234,254)
    WINDOW.fill(COLOUR)

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.draw.circle(WINDOW, COLOUR2, (y, z), 20)
    pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW,COLOUR3,(y+10,z+5,25,8), 7)
    pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW,COLOUR3,(y+35,z+7,10,4), 5)
    pygame.display.update()

    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Can you modify your question to a specific and narrow problem? Posting your whole code is too much noise and won't help any future readers.